# Showing ProgressDialog while a work in progress ( background process ) using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which require accessing a website for data, and will show that data on device. I wants to fetch data from Internet in background and show ProgressDialog while retrieving the data...

but when i run it,it wil not show anything including the layout since background retrieve data from the web...
any help pls

```
package com.hive.listviewimgtext;

                import java.io.BufferedReader;
                import java.io.IOException;
                import java.io.InputStream;
                import java.io.InputStreamReader;
                import java.io.StringReader;
                import java.net.MalformedURLException;
                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.HashMap;

                import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
                import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;


                import static com.hive.listviewimgtext.Contants.XML_URL;

                import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
                import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
                import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
                import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
                import org.w3c.dom.Document;
                import org.w3c.dom.Element;
                import org.w3c.dom.Node;
                import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
                import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

                import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
                import android.net.NetworkInfo;
                import android.os.AsyncTask;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.os.StrictMode;
                import android.util.Log;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.Window;
                import android.widget.AdapterView;
                import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
                import android.widget.LinearLayout;
                import android.widget.ListView;
                import android.widget.TextView;
                import android.widget.Toast;
                import android.annotation.TargetApi;
                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.app.AlertDialog;
                import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.DialogInterface;
                import android.content.Intent;
                ;

                public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {

                    private int e2;
                    public static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
                    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
                    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
                    public static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
                    public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
                    public static final String KEY_IMG_URL = "thumb_url";
                    public  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songlist;
                    public LazyAdapter adapter;
                    public ListView lv;
                    public LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress; 
                    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> ast;

                    @TargetApi(9)
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customized_list_view);

                        linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
                        linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                        songlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


                        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                                String lol = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowid)).getText().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lol, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent _intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),jsonactivity.class);
                                startActivity(_intent);
                            }

                        });
                        Log.d("Reach", "I don reach here");
                        ast = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    @TargetApi(9)
                                    public void run() {
                                        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                                                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                                        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                                        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                                             String xml = getXmlFromUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml");
                                             if(xml.isEmpty()){
                                                 dialogConnection();
                                             }else{
                                                 Document doc = getDomElement(xml);
                                                 NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
                                                 for(int i = 0;i < nl.getLength();i++){
                                                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                                                    HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                    maps.put(KEY_ID, getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                                                    maps.put(KEY_TITLE, getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                                                    maps.put(KEY_ARTIST, getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                                                    maps.put(KEY_DURATION,getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                                                    maps.put(KEY_IMG_URL, getValue(e, KEY_IMG_URL));
                                                    songlist.add(maps);
                                                 }                       
                                                 adapter = new LazyAdapter(CustomizedListView.this, songlist);
                                             }
                                        }else{
                                            dialogConnection();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                return null;
                            }

                            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        };

                        //ast.execute(null,null,null); 

                    }



                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    private void dialogConnection(){
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                CustomizedListView.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("No Connection");

                        alertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connection");


                        alertDialog.setButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                                    ast.execute(null,null,null);
                                }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                    private String getValue(Element item, String key){
                        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(key);
                        return getElementValue(n.item(0));
                    }

                    private final String getElementValue(Node elem){
                        Node child;
                        if(elem != null){
                            if(elem.hasChildNodes()){
                                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()){
                                    if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE){
                                        return child.getNodeValue();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                    private Document getDomElement(String xml){
                        Document doc = null;
                        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        try {
                            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                            doc = db.parse(is);
                            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e2 = Log.e("Error : ", e.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        }
                        return doc;
                    }

                    private String getXmlFromUrl(String pointer){
                        String xml = null;
                        InputStream is = null;
                        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                            try {
                                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(pointer);
                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String line;
                            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                            try {
                                BufferedReader br = new 
                                        BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                                while((line = br.readLine() )!= null){
                                    response.append(line);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                dialogConnection();
                            }
                            xml = response.toString();

                            Log.d("oh oh", "The response is: " + xml);
                        } else {
                            dialogConnection();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        return xml;
                    }
                }
```

my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cool Stuff" 
        />
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:listSelector="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
         android:divider="#b5b5b5"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
package com.hive.listviewimgtext;

                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.HashMap;

                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.TextureView;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
                import android.widget.ImageView;
                import android.widget.TextView;

                public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                    private Activity activity;
                    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data; 
                    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
                    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d){
                        activity = a;
                        data = d;
                        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    }
                    public int getCount() {
                        return data.size();
                    }

                    public Object getItem(int pos) {
                        return pos;
                    }

                    public long getItemId(int pos) {
                        return pos;
                    }

                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View vi = convertView;
                        if(convertView == null)
                            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
                        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
                        TextView rowid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.rowid);
                        ImageView list_image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        song = data.get(position);

                        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
                        rowid.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ID));
                        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
                        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
                        ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
                        il.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_IMG_URL), list_image);
                        return vi;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: what error you are facing.??

Comment: it is not showing the interface(layout) @ all until it fetch the XML